# How can I test whether a for loop is available in the Class?

Tags: java, junit, reflection

Let me explain the use case first.

The use case is that a learner learning `java` is following a set of written instructions and using automated tests (read `JUnit`), I want to test whether they have successfully implemented the instruction.

Things that I need to find out programmatically, for example, is if a `for` loop exists in the code. Consider the following code

```java
class AClass {
    public static void main(String[] args){
         for(int i=1; i<11; i++){
              System.out.println("Count is: " + i);
         }
    }
}
```

Is there a way that using reflection API, I can assert that `AClass` contains `for(int i=1; i<11; i++)`? Or any other way?

This question is an example. Ideally, there could be a code such as `if (x) {}` that I may want to find out inside a class.

I am not sure how feasible this is.

Thank you

Comment: It would probably be easier to dump the byte code with `javap -v AClass.class` and examine that.

Comment: Even if you examine the bytecode, there's no way you can find out if it had a `for` loop. You'll need a source code parser. I probably wouldn't bother.

Comment: Well, sounds like task for lexer, something like https://jflex.de/ on Java . But complexity could be deadly.  Maybe just to use simple regular expressions and pattern matching?

Comment: Have you considered writing a javac plugin?

https://openjdk.java.net/groups/compiler/processing-code.html

Comment: A unit test should verify that a particular unit produces the correct result for a specific input, not whether it contains a loop. How the code under test achieves the result, is entirely irrelevant. If a programmer finds an optimization that allows getting the correct result without a loop, it doesn’t make the code incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Reflection obviously won't help here, because it won't allow access to internals of the method (instructions like `for`, `if`, etc).

From the question it looks like you're working on some kind of learning system that would provide an automatic evaluation/grading of the student's work

So as I see it you have two choices:

1. You also have an access to the source code, so the presence of the `for` loop can be a task to the source code analyzer that would run even before the Junit. A kind of extra step that will check that the student doesn't cheat:

```
// OK - this will pass
public void methodToImplement() {  
  for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    System.out.println("Hello: " + i); 
  }
}

// this is an attempt to cheat that should be recognized:
public void methodToImplement() {  
  System.out.println("Hello: " + 0); 
  System.out.println("Hello: " + 1); 
  System.out.println("Hello: " + 2); 
}
```

2. You can access the bytecode by "reading" it (like opening the *.class file and reading into memory the set of instructions as if its a string or something)  and searching for specific instruction, but then you don't really have a guarantee that the compiler won't do some sort of optimization and will deliberately eliminate the loop (OK, in this example this might not happen, I'm not really an expert in Compiler optimizations, but you get the idea in general).

Comment: The clean solution is to adapt the requirement to make the `3` a parameter. If someone finds a cheat that still works for arbitrary `int` arguments, well, (s)he deserves a price.